# Does a thaumaturge knows all invocations

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, class, spheres-of-power

The [thaumaturge](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/thaumaturge) is confusing.  The class progression table has "invocations" at several levels, and the entry for the ability does not state how many they know:

> Thaumaturges control power in its purest form; whether through bargains with outsiders, the summoning of primal spirits, or simply an untamable spark in their soul, a thaumaturge can invoke a limited amount of truly wondrous power.
>
> A thaumaturge may use invocations a number of times per day equal to his casting ability modifier, which refreshes when he rests to regain spell points. Whenever an invocation calls for a saving throw, the DC is equal to 10 + 1/2 the thaumaturge’s level + the thaumaturge’s casting ability modifier. A thaumaturge may only use invocations of his level or lower. Using an invocation is a free action that may be taken even when it isn't the Thaumaturge's turn.

I checked in the [extra *X* feat](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/extra-feats#toc6) section, and extra invocations only allows 2 more daily uses.

So I am prone to believe they know all invocations, but given the pattern from other PF/SP classes of *pick N from the list below at the given levels* the thaumaturge may seem to follow this, from the table progression.

#### Does a thaumaturge knows all invocations up to the class level they can cast?

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, you know all of them

Invocations have a minimum required level to be used, so a 1st level thaumaturge can only use *Meditation*, *Lingering Pain* and *Lingering Blessing*. Once they reach 3nd level, both *Empowered Defense* and *Empowered Attack* will unlock. Then 4 levels later (7th) they will unlock *Channel Punishment*. And so on, unlocking new Invocations every 4 levels in the class.

So, it may seem like they have too many abilities, but they are unlocked gradually, not all at once. This is similar in design on how [bards](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard) and [skalds](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald) gain their new songs automatically once they reach a certain level.

You will also notice that thaumaturges gain magic talents similarly to half-casters like the [Armorist](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/armorist) or [Mage Knight](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/mageknight), capping at 10/11 talents. But they have a full caster level progression, like the [Fey Adept](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/fey-adept) or [Soul Weaver](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/soul-weaver), which cap at caster level 20. This means that the class, though a full caster, is not as versatile as other full caster classes, and they balance that out with their Invocations.